# Do something after response is finished?

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

What im trying to do is add in array some data after response is finished.
Im trying to check if reponse is ready but without success:

```
this.$http.post('/blog/article/' + articleid + '/comment', article_comments)
.then(function (response) {
    self.comment_id = response.data.comments.id;
    this.user = response.data.comments.user;
    this.dataReady = true;
  }, function (response) {

});

if (this.dataReady == true) {
  this.comments.push({
      comment: this.comment,
      downvotes: 0,
      upvotes: 0,
      user:this.user,
      date_ago: moment(Date.now()).fromNow()
    })
  this.loadComments();
  console.log(this.comments);
}
```

How can i fix this? Because i need data from response and then to push in array, or i will get an error if im trying to push in array before reponse is finished.

Comment: You could use more of promises. If you return the response you can concatenate the `.then` with another `.then(function (response) {...})`. It will make those async calls with a proper logic sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put following code, which you want to execute after getting the response in a method: say `updateOtherVars`:

```
if(this.dataReady == true){
        this.comments.push({
            comment: this.comment,
            downvotes: 0,
            upvotes: 0,
            user:this.user,
            date_ago: moment(Date.now()).fromNow()

          })
            this.loadComments();
              console.log(this.comments);
      }
```

and call this method from the `this.$http` block, like following:

```
this.$http.post('/blog/article/' + articleid + '/comment', article_comments).then(function(response){
          self.comment_id = response.data.comments.id;
          this.user = response.data.comments.user;
          this.dataReady = true;
          this.updateOtherVars()   //Call method from here
        },function(response){

      });
```